Files not listed when mounting VM image with guestmount
When I mount the disk image of a (stopped) KVM virtual machine, ls shows the home and tmp directories as empty, even though inside the virtual machine they are not empty and on the next run (after guestunmount) still are not. This is the command that I use:
guestmount -a bla/bla/bla.qcow2 -m /dev/sda2 -o allow_other -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -r /mnt/vm

sda2 definitively is the only meaningful partition in the image. Both host and guest are openSUSE Tumbleweed.

Home is actually on a partition other than /, that's it. /tmp may very well be empty as it's usually emptied each reboot. Try mounting the other partitions of the VM, one of them shuld have the contents of /home in it.

There are only two other partitions: sda1 only contains the directory EFI, sda3 is the swap partition. Concerning tmp: In the VM, I put files there (as root), then shut down the VM, then invoke guestmount, so those files should still be in there.

What does /etc/fstab look like?

The content of /etc/fstab of the guestmounted VM image (no UUIDs and whitespace due to character limit in this comment):
/ btrfs  defaults 0  0   /var btrfs  subvol=/@/var 0  0 /usr/local btrfs  subvol=/@/usr/local 0  0 /srv btrfs  subvol=/@/srv 0  0 /root btrfs  subvol=/@/root 0  0 /opt btrfs  subvol=/@/opt 0  0 /home btrfs  subvol=/@/home 0  0 /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi btrfs subvol=/@/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  0  0 /boot/grub2/i386-pc btrfs subvol=/@/boot/grub2/i386-pc  0  0 swap swap defaults 0  0 /.snapshots btrfs  subvol=/@/.snapshots 0  0 /boot/efi vfat utf8 0  2

The content of the home directory resides in a subvolume on sda2 called @. The following works:
guestfish -a blah/blah/blah.qcow2 --ro -m /dev/sda2:/:subvol=@
And then on the interactive console created by that command:
ls /home/blah/Downloads
download /home/blah/Downloads/blah.jpg ~blah/Desktop/blah.jpg
quit

